# What does "key" and "Key" mean in response when upload file success to S3?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I'm new to ASW, I wonder What does "key" and "Key" mean in response when upload file success to S3? I see they have the same value.

Thank you in advance!

[image: Code]

```
const uploadVideoToS3 = (originalName, buffer) => { console.log("uploadVideoToS3 called");
// set file name on S3-bitbucket 
let fileName = Date.now() + '-' + originalName.replace(/\s/g, "-"); 
const videoFileName = videos/${fileName}; 
// Setting up S3 upload parameters 
const params = { Bucket: bucketName, Key: videoFileName, Body: buffer } 
// Uploading files to the bucket 
return s3.upload(params).promise();
```

Comment: To what "response" are you referring? Can you show us some code and the contents of the 'response'?

Comment: @JohnRotenstein I had add the image, please help me

Comment: What was the code that returned this response? Was it an API call to S3? Can you show us your code? Please add it to your Question as TEXT, not as an image.

Comment: yes, the image is result return from API

Comment: What was the code that returned this response? Was it an API call to S3? Can you show us your code?

Comment: const uploadVideoToS3 = (originalName, buffer) => {
    console.log("uploadVideoToS3 called");
    // set file name on S3-bitbucket
    let fileName = Date.now() + '-' + originalName.replace(/\s/g, "-");
    const videoFileName = `videos/${fileName}`;

    // Setting up S3 upload parameters
    const params = {
        Bucket: bucketName,
        Key: videoFileName,
        Body: buffer
    }

    // Uploading files to the bucket
    return s3.upload(params).promise();
}

Comment: here is my code

Comment: The [AWS SDK for JavaScript - Amazon S3 documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/latest/AWS/S3.html) only shows return values of `Location`, `Etag`, `Bucket` and `Key`. So, I'm not sure where your system is getting `key` (lowercase).

Comment: I don't know, but value of "Key" and that in "key" are the same

Comment: If you were coding to extract a value, you should use `Key` since that is referenced in the documentation.